# Italicising a Single Word In a HTML Placeholder

Tags: html, css

I would like to italicise a single word in a HTML placeholder attribute. I've tried `<i></i>` and `<span>` with css styling but neither work since it only accepts plaintext, right?

From my google searches so far the only solutions have been to italicise the entire thing using CSS but I need to format a single word.

If anyone could provide assistance I'd be extremely thankful.

Comment: HTML5 Placeholder does not support this. Only way to do this is to create stacked elements (positioned on top of each other) and then style the element that functions as placeholder according to your wishes. That goes beyond the scope of an answer (you'd need a HTML + CSS tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative answer: You use a paragraph as your placeholder, positioned absolutely within a div wrapper that also contains the input. It is important to explicitly position the wrapper relatively. The paragraph must have no pointer events. Here I'm using the required input property, together with the `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-classes to know when to hide the placeholder, which is a bit overly hacky and might not behave as you want.

HTML:

```
<input placeholder="This is a placeholder"/>
<br />
<div class="italics">
  <input required />
  <p class="specific">Now <i>THIS</i> is a placeholder</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.italics {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;

}

.italics input[value=""] {
  display: none;
}

.italics input:valid + p {
  display: none;
}

.italics input:invalid + p {
  display: inline !important;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: gray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

https://codepen.io/differentsmoke/pen/KezLdj

Comment: Thank you, this works but has some issues with IE, working on rectifying those now.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you may be able to get around this using UNICODE italics characters (https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=italic)

Here's what should be a complete lowercase set (for English)  . You'll be restricted to serif fonts, though.

I believe anything other than this will require some hacking.

Comment: Creative approach, perhaps with some limitations, but still! I always wondered however why Unicode even has italics...

Comment: Aha, so then it might not work for e.g. `é`, `à`, etc

Comment: The limitations are quite bothersome but It might do the trick. Thank you :)